# I want to know about what difference happens with / and \ when we use them in path.join and path.resolve, how does it actually works?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
const path = require("node:path");

console.log(path.join("folder1", "folder2", "index.html"));
console.log(path.join("/folder1", "folder2", "index.html"));
console.log(path.join("\folder1", "folder2", "index.html"));
console.log(path.join("\\folder1", "folder2\\", "index.html"));
console.log(path.join("//folder1", "//folder2", "/index.html/"));
console.log(path.join("folder1", "folder2", "../index.html"));
console.log(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));

console.log(path.resolve("folder1", "folder2", "index.html"));
console.log(path.resolve("/folder1", "folder2", "index.html"));
console.log(path.resolve("\folder1", "folder2", "index.html"));
console.log(path.resolve("\\folder1", "folder2\\", "index.html"));
console.log(path.resolve("//folder1", "//folder2", "/index.html/"));
console.log(path.resolve("folder1", "folder2", "../index.html"));
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"));
```

Following was output of the above code I tried:

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\learning> node index    
folder1\folder2\index.html
\folder1\folder2\index.html

older1\folder2\index.html
\folder1\folder2\index.html
\\folder1\folder2\index.html\
folder1\index.html
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\learning\index.html
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\learning\folder1\folder2\index.html
C:\folder1\folder2\index.html
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\learning\
older1\folder2\index.html
C:\folder1\folder2\index.html
C:\index.html
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\learning\folder1\index.html
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\learning\index.html
```

I want to why sometimes there are differences when I use / and \ , how does both of them with these two methods.

Comment: `\f` is an escape character called Form Feed

Comment: what does it do ?